# How to get/provide tpl file of editing a field collection?

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I want to theme a my collection field on the edit page. I have several fields in one collection and that collection gets all the height of the screen.

Though, I want the values of the collection field to fit on 200px to 300px height. To achieve this I need to override the tpl file... But how to know the name of tpl to be overriden ?

Has anyone got a clue ?

Comment: Are you positive you can not build the form layout better with grouping fields, using hook_form_alter, hook_field_widget_form_alter and prerender callbacks and css. Personally I have begun to feel like that templates are evil.

Comment: Sure, I could but the result won't be very userfriendly as I need... I also need to know if there's a possible template for editing the field in admin iterface or not as a knowledge base...